# Getting Record Value while Looping through a Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario**:

1. select records from one TableA
2. loop through the table values
3. delete from another table (TableB) based on each record's value

**Sample**:

```
DECLARE @CustomerList TABLE (CustomerID bigint) 
INSERT INTO @CustomerList SELECT CustomerID FROM TableA WHERE CustomerID = @ParameterID

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @CustomerList) > 0
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [TableB]
WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerList.CustomerID -- challenge
END
```

**Challenge**:

- Passing the CustomerID value of each loop

**Update**

- The reason for wanting to use a loop is that there are multiple delete statements to be executed

Comment: Running multiple deletes is NOT a valid reason for using a loop. If you need multiple deletes just code the multiple deletes. Doing this is a loop is completely the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: @SeanLange, can you check John's answer...it looks right logically to me at least from a coding background point of view vs sql. Repeating the same select statement for each delete statement sounds inefficient.

Comment: I would use a join but either way is light years more efficient than using a loop!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why loop?

```
Delete From [Table B]
 Where [CustomerID] in (Select CustomerID from TableA where SomeCondition=true)
```

OK, then to support multiple deletes.  You can keep your table variable

```
DECLARE @CustomerList TABLE (CustomerID bigint) 
INSERT INTO @CustomerList SELECT CustomerID FROM TableA WHERE CustomerID = @ParameterID

Delete From [Table B] Where [CustomerID] in (Select CustomerID from @CustomerList)
Delete From [Table C] Where [CustomerID] in (Select CustomerID from @CustomerList)
```

Comment: The reason is that there are actually multiple delete statements...I updated the answer. Now I am not sure if using this technique still the most efficient way to do it since I will have to call the select statement multiple times

Comment: I would probably use a join but either way this is light years more efficient than a loop for this!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use join, instead of while. Something like below.

```
DELETE t
FROM TableB as t
join @CustomerList as c
on t.CustomerID = C.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need a temp table or a loop. A join should work.

Example:

```
DELETE B
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A
  ON B.CustomerID=A.CustomerID
WHERE A.CustomerID = @ParameterID
```